# "Choose how to enter input" - leave me alone

Tags: front-end, notebooks

How do I get rid of this:

> [image: Choose how to enter input]

I can't find the appropriate entry in Option Inspector or in [WolframPredictiveInterface](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/WolframPredictiveInterface.html).

Comment: On the brighter side, at least Wolfram did not choose to harass us with a paperclip…

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is called the "Cell insertion menu". Its appearance is defined in `MiscExpressions.tr` via the front end resource `"CellInsertionMenu"`.

Notebooks (depending on the stylesheet, of course) have it defined as a "cell insertion point cell" by default:

```
AbsoluteOptions[SelectedNotebook[], "CellInsertionPointCell"]
(* -> {CellInsertionPointCell -> 
       FEPrivate`FrontEndResource["FEExpressions", "CellInsertionMenu"]} *)
```

We can disable it as follows:

```
SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], "CellInsertionPointCell" -> Cell[]] (* gone *)
```

To kill this pop-up at the Stylesheet level one may use **Edit Stylesheet** and insert:

```
Cell[StyleData[All, "Working"],
 CellInsertionPointCell -> None
]
```

Comment: Ha, would've never expected you to answer a [tag:front-end] question! :)