# Creating "detached" plots

Tags: plotting, gui-construction, interactive, user-interface

Is it possible to create detached interactive plots in *Mathematica* like those in MATLAB, Jupyter (IPython), etc. rather than inline ones?

This is an interactive GIF from Rodeo IDE for Python as an example, click on it if it is not giffy. It is quite long animation.

[image: example from Rodeo IDE]

Comment: You might be referring to CDFs. Look in the docs under `howto/CreateAComputableDocumentFormatFile`.

Comment: …or are you asking how to make plots act like pop-ups?

Comment: @J. M., Yes, plot act like popups. Patrick, Not sure what's the point of CDF?  CDF for each detached plot?

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of what you want to obtain, e.g. a result from one of those programs you mention? It may make it easier to answer your question if we know exactly what you are after.

Comment: @MarcoB, I inserted one gif example from rodeo ide

Comment: Somewhat related: [(70185)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/70185/121)

Answer (score 24):

> If you are serious about using this extensively, consider making a function based on `CreateDocument`...

Here is one way to pursue Szabolcs's line of thought. What follows is a function based on `CreateDocument[]` that can be used in conjunction with the (now somewhat neglected) option `DisplayFunction`, which handles where the output of graphics functions should be shown.

First, the custom display function:

```
popup[gr_] := CreateDocument[gr, "CellInsertionPointCell" -> Cell[], 
                             ShowCellBracket -> False, WindowElements -> {}, 
                             WindowFrame -> "Generic", WindowSize -> All,
                             WindowTitle -> None, WindowToolbars -> {}]
```

(thanks to Oleksandr for [`"CellInsertionPointCell"`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/66895).)

Using it is now as simple as

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 π}, DisplayFunction -> popup]
```

which should yield a small window like this on Linux:

[image: popup plot in Linux]

or this on Windows (thanks to belisarius):

[image: popup plot in Windows]

or this on Mac OS X  (thanks to Jens):

[image: popup plot in Mac OS X]

It will also work with 3D graphics, and will of course retain the interactivity.

---

A variation proposed by Szabolcs uses `DocumentNotebook[]` instead of `CreateDocument[]`:

```
popup[gr_] := DocumentNotebook[gr, "CellInsertionPointCell" -> Cell[], 
                               ShowCellBracket -> False, WindowElements -> {}, 
                               WindowFrame -> "Generic", WindowSize -> All,
                               WindowTitle -> None, WindowToolbars -> {}]
```

This produces a cell that is a mini-notebook of sorts, with a button that yields a popup version of the plot if pressed.

Comment: What interactivity do you mean?

Comment: I mean, the 3D graphics in the popup can still be rotated, zoomed into, etc.

Comment: Here are some comments/suggestions:  1, `WindowFrame -> "ThinFrame"` has no title bar and its not closeable or movable on OS X. 2, 3D graphics can't easily be rotated without `SphericalRegion -> True` or `RotationAction -> "Clip"`. 3, You could also set `$DisplayFunction` globally.  (But non-plotting functions don't apply `DisplayFunction` without `Show`)  4, I really like `DocumentNotebook` instead of `CreateDocument` here because it doesn't pop out the window immediately but it does give a popout button.  (@denfromufa)

Comment: @Szabolcs. 1. I explicitly set `WindowTitle -> None` since I wasn't sure how to name the popup, and leaving it as "Untitled-n" seemed unseemly. What do you suggest as a replacement for `WindowFrame -> "ThinFrame"`? 2. I guess I can do special processing for `Graphics3D[]` arguments. 4. I'll try that alternate; however, if memory serves, MATLAB just pops out the plot at once, and I'd thought the OP would want something like it.

Comment: cool, but you need to have it appear behind all my other windows for a true *matlab-like* experience.   ("ThinFrame" makes a window you cant get rid of on windows too, btw )

Comment: @george, hah, don't remember MATLAB doing that, but it's been ages since I used it... :)

Comment: @Sjoerd, I'd credit that to being well-versed with `DisplayFunction` gymnastics back in the days of old *Mathematica*. :)

Comment: Yeah, but we mostly did `DisplayFunction->Identity` and `DisplayFunction->$DisplayFunction`.

Comment: @J. M. is away, I would like to ask how to apply this method to non-graphics object? I have a "plot" generated using `Column[{Overlay[{plot11, plot1}], Overlay[{plot22, plot2}]}, Spacings -> 0]`. But `DisplayFunction`is an option for graphics and sound functions. I tried `GraphicColumn`. But because of the problem mentioned [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/5708788/4336241), I cannot get it done. Could you please give me some suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: What about killing the last window that was created, or reploting it? If you run the function again it will open a new window instead of updating the last one.

Answer (score 18):

You can always create a new notebook and put things in it.  If you are serious about using this extensively, consider making a function based on `CreateDocument` that sets the appropriate options for the notebook to look good.

Check what `CreateDocument@Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,10}]` does.

Or use a quick-and-dirty hack based on `CreatePalette`:

```
fig = CreatePalette[#, Background -> White, Saveable -> False] &

fig@MandelbrotSetPlot[]
```

You could also use `PaletteNotebook` instead of `CreateDocument`.  This won't pop out the palette, it just adds a button to do it manually.